# JAVA: apply width and height to fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm new to JAVA (Android development) and want to apply a width and a height to a fragment. I've pointed out that this is not possible, but what is the alternative? Wrap it in an extra layout, ... ?

In the oncreate method (of the java file that instantiates the fragment) this is what I have. It creates the fragment that fills the whole screen of my device.

```
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
Fragment playerFrag = new PlayerFragment();
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(rl.getId(), playerFrag).commit();
```

This is what i tried to apply a width and height:

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);

ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = playerFrag.getView().getLayoutParams();
params.width = displaymetrics.widthPixels/2;
params.height = displaymetrics.heightPixels/2;
playerFrag.getView().setLayoutParams(params);
```

Any suggestions on this issue, tips?

Comment: Firstly, this question shouldn't be tagged with Java as it is about Android concepts regardless of which programming language you're using. Secondly, the size of the `Fragment` is dictated by the size of the layout in which it's placed. In most cases you'd use a `FrameLayout` as a placeholder and add the `Fragment` to that. By controlling the size and position of the `FrameLayou`, you control the size and position of the `Fragment`. I suggest you follow a few tutorials on using `Fragments`.

Comment: You can set param.width = 900
param.height = 900